# Transactional Support in Python/Django

Tags: python, django, transactions

I'm building a website that needs transactional support so that database record modifications will succeed or fail as a unit. I really like the object-relational mapping that Django/Python provide. Do they also provide a transactional facility that automatically "roll back" previous model insertions if a subsequent database modification in a unit fails?

Comment: could you provide the version of django you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, Yes. Django has a bunch of APIs to control how transaction happens when you run Queries.

Long answer, The transaction management API in django has changed a lot over the different versions. Please check the documentation of the version of django you are using.

I will leave you with a couple of pointers.
from [database transactions in django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/transactions/)

the default behaviour is that django runs each query inside a transaction. The query is committed as soon as it is executed.

If you need a bunch of ORM queries to pass or fail as a unit, there are decorators/context managers provided by django for transaction management.

particularly, take a look at [atomic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic)
decorator/ctxt manager or the django.db.transaction module if you are using django < 1.6